# How to stop Navigation Drawer from disabling my activity?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Let's say I have an activity with two fragments X and Y horizontally placed side by side and one hidden navigation drawer fragment. Whenever I click on a button on the fragment X, the navigation drawer fragment slides from right and takes place above the Y fragment. As I made it transparent, now users can see the X fragment along with the navigation drawer fragment horizontally placed side by side. But this navigation drawer fragment disables the X fragment as it overlays the activity actually. How can I keep the activity transition alive when the navigation drawer is open?

Comment: Why do you want to fight against the system? If the Activity should be alive, don't use a navigation drawer.

Comment: I agree with Henry, but this has been answered here before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743124/make-main-content-area-active-in-drawerlayout

Comment: Henry, I might need to save the state of the fragment Y and replace it every time with the state. That is why, I was thinking about the navigation drawer. 

Mike, my problem is similar, let me have a look. I could not find the question on stackoverflow. Thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom class for your Navigartion Drawer

```
public class CustomDrawer extends DrawerLayout {

public CustomDrawer(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    View drawer = getChildAt(1);

    if (getDrawerLockMode(drawer) == LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN && ev.getRawX() > drawer.getWidth()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
}
```

I had the same question. This code is from here [Make fragment clickable when navigation drawer is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486385/make-fragment-clickable-when-navigation-drawer-is-opened)

Comment: Thank You! This solved my problem :) :)