# Cannot interact with fragments when drawer layout is open

Tags: android, android-fragments, drawerlayout, androiddesignsupport, navigationview

I have built an application using the [Android Design Support Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM4YS.jpg).
My app has a DrawerLayout with a NavigationView which works just as I would expect it to.

I am now trying to add some tablet support to my app and I want it to work so that when the app is in landscape mode the Drawer Layout is always open.

At the moment I have managed to achieve this like so:

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
{
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
    mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));         
}
```

This works fine, which leads me to my issue. Switching between menu options in the Drawer Layout switches out the fragment in my FrameLayout.

However, I cannot scroll the view in the fragment, nor can I select anything or press any buttons in the fragment.

Does anyone know how I can enable such behaviour? Or is it not possible using the Android Design Support Library?

Ideally I would like my app to work like PocketCasts does. (See below screenshot).

[Screenshot of PocketCasts Nav Menu and Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM4YS.jpg)

[image]

Comment: It would probably be preferable to use a different layout for the tablet landscape - one that just has a `NavigationView` next to the rest of your layout - but if you want to keep the `DrawerLayout` for some reason, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743124/make-main-content-area-active-in-drawerlayout) demonstrates how to do what you're describing.

Comment: I ended up implementing a different layout for the tablet landscape in the end. Thanks for the suggestion. For some reason I thought NavigationView would only work if it was in a DrawerLayout.